# Корзина angular.js

Tags: angularjs, cart

Нужно сменить значок `$` на `руб` в корзине, два дня ищу не могу найти, и убрать две цифры после точки.

Вот ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankcastro/7g02cs8g/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/frankcastro/7g02cs8g

Comment: Добавте фрагмент кода из ссылки непосредственно в вопрос. Ссылка когда-то устареет и Ваши вопрос с ответом станут полностью безполезными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь, ответ 
это {{ ngCart.totalCost() | currency: }}
заменить на это {{ ngCart.totalCost() | currency: "RUB" }}